# IndDesign - chapter name XML

Tags: adobe-indesign, import, xml

As I am preparing a catalogue in InDesign based on xml import.
Ideal would be that the chapter titles would be imported as well as a variable/xml tag.
That would mean I can have 1 xml file and 1 .indt .
Is this possible?
I experimented with running headers, but how to include this data in a xml?

The way I do it now:

- for each chapter 1 InDesign template (24x)
- and as many XML files to import (24x)

No problem, but I perhaps it could be done more efficiently.

thanks

Comment: I’m having a hard time figuring out what exactly you’re trying to do here. What do you mean by ‘chapter titles’ exactly? What is a ‘variable/XML tag’? Why does there have to be an .indt file (that is, a document template, rather than just an InDesign document)? And how do the running headers fit in exactly? It is easy enough to match a specific tag to a specific paragraph style, which you’d use to make headers (‘titles’) in the document which can then be used as the basis for running headers. Is that what you’re looking for?

Comment: Perhaps I got the concept wrong, I will look into it again after your text.

Comment: The main issue is: I have an xml file with products, which all need to appear in different chapters. The xml has been structured as <items><item>product 1</item><item>product ..</item></items>